# How to Make a VideoView in Android?

Tags: android

I would like to make a Opening Video to the App, which is settled, but how to make a videoview to do it? How do I set up the java class and xml layout?

Here's my code for the basic

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
     }
}
```

Comment: I have explained here how to create a splash movie Activity http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/09/how-to-create-splash-activity-best.html

Comment: I I want to just have it just a little part of the screeen and continue with the rest of the activity text

Comment: Okay I'm upset the splash activity crashed

Comment: You will have to set the layoutParams of the VideoView

Comment: I don't want a splash I want an actual stop play and pause video